# How to save the session

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have created a function here :

```
router.get('/restful',function(req,res,next){
  var resultArray=[];
  mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
    assert.equal(null,err);
    var cursor=db.collection('users').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
      assert.equal(null,err);
      resultArray.push(doc);
      req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
    },function(){
      db.close();
      res.render('restful',{items:resultArray});
          });

});
});
```

I have created a method/restful. The "restful" is a page.

All I want is when I load this page, the resultArray gets displayed, but it's not displayed at the first load.

It's displaying after we navigate it for the second time. So the data is not being retrieved.

How can I solve this issue?

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is due to the nature of how sessions work in node.js, but you may want to reference: https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions

I would move `req.session.resultArray` out of the `forEach` as there is no benefit to overwriting the session multiple times when you're already building the array for its value, you can just set it later after you've built the entire array.

This shouldn't be an issue with needing to invoke a redirect to view the new session data because we're not even technically messing with accessing a cookie or session (yet), we're using `res.render()` to make a variable `items` expose an internal variable for `resultArray` within our view. Although if you want to play with that you can use `res.redirect('/restful')` to invoke a redirect where data should already be initialized.

I would look at something like this

```
router.get('/restful', function( req, res, next ) {
  var resultArray = [];
  mongo.connect(url, function( err, db ) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    var cursor = db.collection('users').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
      assert.equal(null, err);
      resultArray.push(doc);
    });
    db.close();
  });
  req.session.resultArray = resultArray;
  // this should contain your
  // session data
  console.log(resultArray);
  res.render('restful', {items:resultArray});  
  next();
});
```

But I would like to note, the problem you are facing is not with session data not saving or being accessible so to speak, but rather that at the time of `res.render()` your `resultArray` does not appear to be built yet as you're only exposing this variable to your view.

I would play around with logging your `resultArray` and the answer should become clear to you.

Comment: That is to say, if I understand your question correctly. I understand it as `items` is not being populated until a page refresh.

Comment: After i tried the above code.The resultArray is not populating with the values.It is having null values.

Comment: can you `console.log(doc)` in your forEach loop to make sure it's getting the correct documents on the first go around? If not we need to start looking at MongoDB specifically, and perhaps how the Object is being stored into the Array.

Comment: I have tried it out after resultArray.push(doc) If we console.log()it.Its showing the data.But req.session.resultArray() if we try it out .Its not fetching the values. @recursiveoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486309/how-to-pass-function-value/42486396?noredirect=1#comment72118166_42486396                             I have tried dis way too to get the data.But I am not being able to fetch the data and store it.can u suggest out some ways

Comment: you can try to use `req.session.save()` but again it should be building the Array in the route and that array should be fully accessible, I think I misunderstood your question. Is it that you are building the Array without a problem, however when you access the Session it's empty until reload? Please try to use `res.redirect('/restful')` in your route if `req.session.save()` fails

Comment: The array is loaded everything is working but only problem is that on the first load the view is not able to be loaded with data