# how to pass function value

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have created models called (user.js)

```
    module.exports.show_deatils = function(req,res,callback){   
      var resultArray=[];
      mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
        assert.equal(null,err);
        var cursor=db.collection('users').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
          assert.equal(null,err);
          resultArray.push(doc);         
        });
      });
    }

    router.get('/restful', function(req, res){    
      User.show_deatils(function(req,res,resultArray){
        req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
        console.log(resultArray);
      });
      res.render('restful');
    });
```

I have created a `method("show_details")` in models `user.js` and I am calling that particular function in routes. whenever the page (restful) gets loaded I want the data `resultArray` to be displayed. But I am stuck here.

Can you please suggest me how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On your `res` object, you need to pass the variable `resultArray`in your render function, so it becomes available to use in your template.

Something like:

```
res.render('restful', {var_in_ejs_template: resultArray});
```

This is thoroughly documented in express.js's documentation: [link](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render)

Also, don't put the result in the `res.session` property. Looks dirty.

Comment: After doing the same 
    res.render('restful',{items:resultArray});
 });
 This is throwing an error ReferenceError: resultArray is not defined
   at C:\nodeproject\loginapp\routes\users.js:176:33

Comment: @riza It's undefined because you are using it outside your method's callback scope.

Comment: @riza  And your method isn't returning any `resultArray` object when you call it.

Comment: module.exports.show_deatils=function(req,res,callback){

  var resultArray=[];
  mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
    assert.equal(null,err);
    var cursor=db.collection('users').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
      assert.equal(null,err);
      resultArray.push(doc);
      
   
     
    });
  
});
  return resultArray;
} After returning the resultArray still I cant  fetch the value.i am preety new to node.js.Can u please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you user module show_deatils takes two parameters, you are not passing any,
and in callback you are not using,

> user.js

```
module.exports.show_deatils = function(req,res,callback){   
      var resultArray=[];
      mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
        assert.equal(null,err);
        var cursor=db.collection('users').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
          assert.equal(null,err);
          resultArray.push(doc);         
        });
        callback(resultArray);
      });
    }
```

> route

```
 router.get('/restful', function(req, res){    
      User.show_deatils(req,res,function(resultArray){
        req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
        console.log(resultArray);
        res.render('restful');
      });

    });
```